# Writing Custom Transaction Times during Visual Studio Load Test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, transactions, load-testing

Is there a way to write custom transaction times during a loadtest in VisualStudio. Normally to log the transaction time, you put the transaction between the BeginTimer and EndTimer methods like below:

```
TestContext.BeginTimer("TransactionName");
// Do stuff for the transaction here
TestContext.EndTimer("TransactionName");
```

In my code, I already have the timing for the transaction stored. Is there a way for me to report this? Something like this:

```
WriteTimer("TransactionName", time);
```

I would like to see the results in the test summary that Visual Studio creates.

Answer (score 2):

Use the BeginTransaction and EndTransaction methods in place of BeginTimer and EndTimer:

```
TestContext.BeginTransaction ("TransactionName");
// Do stuff for the transaction here
TestContext.EndTransaction ("TransactionName");
```

The results for "TransactionName" will be displayed in the test summary.

Comment: Will it also be added in the LoadTest Database? If not how could we add it?